# Create header names on the csv file from the $_POST values

Tags: php, html

I have a simple form that the contents are populated by pulling data from the database. I use a multi name[] option so I can loop through the data in PHP easily.
The form may expand in future so I do not want to reuse code in the PHP end. I am making a csv from the outputted data and want to create header names on the csv file from the $_POST array() I can access the data but it populates a new row in the csv file instead of a new column.I would also like to output the data from the posted data to new rows. I have tried a few things which I have commented in the code of the result I got when I tried them.

```
// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
{
    //This is where I want to add the $_POST values as headers 
    fputcsv($output, array($Key));//This is what I have tried but it just adds in a new line not column 
}

//I have also tried the following for the rows to add the data into the csv file 

for ( $i = 0; $i < count($_POST) - 0; ++$i) 
{
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
    {
        fputcsv($output, array($Key[$i]));  //This seems to only return the first character 
    }
}//End of for loop
?>

<!-- form is to be populated from a mysql data base in a table  -->

<!-- This pulls the data from the database and loops throgh and displays the data. -->
<form action = "" method = "Post">
<?php while ($row = $prepped->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) :?>    
    <input type="text" name="Firstname[]" value="<?php echo $row->Firstname ; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="Email[]" value="<?php echo $row->Email ; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="LastName[]" value="<?php echo $row->Lastname ; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="Phone[]" value="<?php echo $row->Phone ; ?>">
<?php endwhile;?>
</form>
```

Comment: `$key` is not the same as `$Key`. What should `- 0` in `count($_POST) - 0` do? "_but it just adds in a new line_" Create a line containing your columns and then write that line

Comment: I can do it manually by adding in the $_POST[''] like this but I would rather have it as automated as possible for ( $i = 0; $i < count($_POST['Firstname']) - 0; ++$i) {
   fputcsv($output, array($_POST['Firstname '][$i], $_POST['Phone'][$i] ,$_POST['Email'][$i]));
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$keys=array_keys($_POST);
fputcsv($output, array_keys($_POST));
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST); $i++) 
{
    $result=array();
    foreach($keys as $key => $value) 
    {
        $result[]=$_POST[$value][$i];
    }
    fputcsv($output, $result);
}

exit();
```

You will get key as column name and value as row

Comment: Thank you so much saved me so much time

Answer (score -1):

```
$keys=array_keys($_POST);
fputcsv($output, array_keys($_POST));
do { 
    $result=array();
    $i++;
    foreach($keys as $key => $value){ 
        $result[]=$_POST[$value][$i]; 
    }
    fputcsv($output, $result);
}

while ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST));
exit();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.